# changing the value of var1

Tags: python, pointers, variable-assignment

My question is more of an understanding question than a strict programming question.
I know that python variables are actually pointers, which means they don't actually store a value, but rather point to the place in memory where that value is stored.
What i can't figure out is how the following 2 cases differ:

```
>>> a = 3
>>> b = a
>>> a
3
>>> b
3
>>>b = 4
>>> b
4
>>> a
3
```

The new value assigned to 'b' does not change the value pointed to by 'a'. As oppose to:

```
>>> a = [1,2,3]
>>> b = a
>>> a
[1,2,3]
>>> b
[1,2,3]
>>> b.append(4)
>>> b
[1,2,3,4]
>>> a
[1,2,3,4]
```

The new value assigned to b changed the value pointed to by a

Comment: a=[1,2,3];   b=a;  b=[7,8,9]; print a; print b; Does this gives u a hint ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calling `b.append` doesn't assign `b` to a new list. It still points to the same position in memory.

```
>>> b = [1,2,3]
>>> id(b)
36586568L
>>> b.append(4)
>>> id(b)
36586568L
```

Since it is the underlying data that changes, any other identifiers also pointing to that data will be affected.

Answer (score 0):

This has been covered many times before.  Short answer is that they aren't strictly pointers.  They are more like labels.  In your top case, b is re-labeled to 4 and thus changes.  In your bottom case (with the array) b is not re-labeled, but only it's contents appended to.  That's why arrays seem to act differently.

Answer (score 0):

Python "variables" ("binding" would be a more appropriate term) are not pointers, they are key->value pairs in a namespace. How the namespace and lookup are implemented is, well, an implementation detail, but you can consider it's a hash table (Python's `dict`).

> The new value assigned to b changed the value pointed to by a

Where do you see the assignement operator in `b.append(4)` ? You're not rebinding `b`, you are mutating it. It's still the same list object that is bound to both names `a` and `b`.